# Configurar certificados de Seguridad para un Subdominio

Tags: apache, ssl

Tengo en mi servidor un dominio con sus certificados SSL, pero el día de hoy me dio por agregar otro subdominio para un proyecto que queremos trabajar aparte y me gustaría poder instalar los certificados para este dominio, pero no se como invocar dos certificados distintos desde apache, se crear mis archivos y obviamente guardarlos en mi pc, pero a la hora de invocarlos cuando no se como configurar el ssl.conf cuando son varias llaves que hay que llamar.

Sistema Operativo: Centos 6.9
Apache Version: 2.2.15

Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener certificados SSL que incluyan subdominios y de este modo desde Apache podrías apuntar al mismo certificado y te serviría para el dominio y el subdominio.

Si el certificado lo sacas con [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/es/), que es gratuito,  tienes 2 opciones:

- Especificar explicitamente que subdominios quieres añadir a tu certificado.
- Desde hace aproximadamente un año también ofrecen certificados para subdominios con comodines (*'wildcards'*) del tipo *.midominio.com. Puedes ampliar esta información [aquí](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578) (en inglés).

Puedes encontrar más información en español en el sitio de [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).